# Magento2 programmatically create Product with the custom option not displaying on frontend

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.2

magento2 custom option created backend but not displaying in the frontend.

```
public function createProduct($data)
    {
        $productName = 'name';
        $product = $this->productModel;
        $product->setSku('test'); 
        $product->setName($productName); 
        $product->setAttributeSetId(4);
        $product->setStatus(1); 
        $product->setWeight(1);
        $product->setVisibility(4);
        $product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
        $product->setTaxClassId(0);
        $product->setTypeId('simple');
        $product->setPrice(100);
        $product->setUrlKey('test');
        $product->setIsDesigntoolProduct(1);
        $product->setStockData(
                array(
                    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
                    'manage_stock' => 1,
                    'is_in_stock' => 1,
                    'qty' => 5
                )
        );

        $product->save();
        $options = array(
                array(
                    "sort_order"    => 1,
                    "title"         => "Demo",
                    "price_type"    => "fixed",
                    "price"         => "0",
                    "type"          => "area",
                    "is_require"   => 0
                )
            );
        $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
        $product->setHasOptions(1);
        foreach ($options as $arrayOption) {

            $product->getResource()->save($product);
            $option = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')
                            ->setProductId($product->getId())
                            ->setStoreId($product->getStoreId())
                            ->addData($arrayOption);
            $option->save();
            $product->addOption($option);
        }
        $product->save();
        return $product;
    }
```

Comment: just a question as i am also learning to create products programmatically , that why dont you use magneto API to create the products ?

Comment: I want it in controller through.

Comment: Can you try again by putting $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true); before for loop as mentioned here:
https://webkul.com/blog/create-custom-option-programmatically-in-magento2/

Comment: yes, I did but not working.

Comment: I updated my answer.